# Improving the speed of writing into a txt file python

Tags: python

I am generating a txt file based on the TD IDF calculation for each words.

I am using this code to write the file

```
w_writer = open("tf_idf_vectors_stops_2.txt", "w")
for x in xrange(0, len(listPatient)):
    patientId = listPatient[x] #List for patientid
    for words in tdDict_final[patientId]:
        w_writer.write(patent + "," + str(multiListTokens.index(words[0])) +     "," + str(words[2]))
        w_writer.write("\n")
w_writer.close()
```

listPatient is a list consisted of sorted ID.

```
 listPatient = ['001', '002', '003', '004']
```

tdDict_final is a dictionary consists of ID as a key and words and words value

In the code we called words[0] for word and word[2] value because word[1] is going to be ":", the format of tdDict_final is shown as this.

```
 {'001': [('dog', ':', '0.2534879), ('cat', ':', '0.0133487)],
  '002': [('floor', ':', '0.047589'), ('board'), ':' ('0.099345)],
  '003': [('key'), ':', '0.04993)],
  '004': [('thanks', ':', '0.01479')]}
```

tdDict contains all the patients in listPatient

multilistTokens is a list contain many distinct vocabularies (tokens)

multilistTokens consists of all the possible dictinct vocabularies found in tdDict.

The problem is, my code above is extremely slow and sluggish when writing it out.

Is there anyway I can improve the efficiency of writing into a txt file using the code above?

Thank you very much

Comment: So patients are patented these days?

Comment: How big are your list & dict; the double loop may be the actual cause of slowness, not the writing to disk.

Comment: Also, have you timed how long something like this piece of code takes: `multiListTokens.index(words[0])`. Just run that inside that double loop, without any writing or anything else, and let us know if that's much faster or just as slow.

Comment: This code should be writing fast unless `multiListTokens` is huge. Does the output file look right?

Comment: len(multiListTokens) is 444032

Comment: @Evert, I tried running only multiListTokens.index(words[0]), it takes almost the same amount of time running the code in my question. I think the large number of vocab insie multiListTokens might influence the speed of the code. Btw, out of context question, are there anyway I can print the amoung time running the code in a cell in Jupiter notebook?

Comment: Yes, so your bottleneck has nothing the do with output, but with finding an element in a list. You'll have to solve that if you want to speed up things, but that may not be straightforward. You could consider, for example, breaking up multilListTokens into a dict with 26 key-values (key based on the first letter), and then a search inside the sublists. There are probably better ways, but it's essentially a different question (or rather, a more specific question than "how to speed up my code?")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
with open("tf_idf_vectors_stops_2.txt", "w") as w_writer:
    for patientId in listPatient:
        for words in tdDict_final[patientId]:
            w_writer.write("%s,%s,%s\n" % (patent, str(multiListTokens.index(words[0])), str(words[2])))
```

**1st** | you should use a `with` statement instead of opening the file and then manually closing the file. The `with` statement is a [python context manager](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0343/), which means that it will open the file as `w_writer` and then when you are finished it will close it automatically.

**2nd** | there is no need to use the `xrange` above, because apart from where you take `patientId` from `listPatient` (`patientId = listPatient[x]`) you are not using the `x`. You can extract `patientId` directly from `listPatient` and use it from there.

**3rd** | using the `+` method to add strings together is notoriously slow in python. The most efficient way to concatenate (join) strings in python is by using the join method or by using in-place delimiters (as I have). Also you should not be calling write twice as you can incorporate the `"\n"` in the 1st write statement.

Comment: `join` for five strings compared to `+`? That really won't make a notable difference. The proposed rewrite with string formatting is more elegant anyway (though I'd prefer `.format()`).

Comment: Actually you would use only one join as such: `"".join([patent, ",", str(multiListTokens.index(words[0])), ",", str(words[2]), "\n"])` and yes it is significantly faster.

Comment: I'm not seeing that for 5 string joined together: `In [16]: %timeit "".join(["asdf", "qwer", "uiop", "zxcv", "vbnm"]) -- 
The slowest run took 14.50 times longer than the fastest. This could mean that an intermediate result is being cached -- 
1000000 loops, best of 3: 388 ns per loop ====
In [17]: %timeit "asdf" + "qwer" + "uiop" + "zxcv" + "vbnm" -- 
The slowest run took 53.08 times longer than the fastest. This could mean that an intermediate result is being cached -- 
100000000 loops, best of 3: 18.9 ns per loop`.

Comment: Even going with the *slowest* runs, to avoid caching, I get 14.5 * 388 = 5626 ns for the `join` method, and 53.08 * 18.9 = 1003 ns for normal string concatenation with `+`.

Comment: @Niche.P Did this solve your speed problem? How much faster is your code now? Since to me it seems the `.index` method is causing the slow down, and that's still there inside a double loop.